# Adding Days in a Select statement of a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, select, datatable

I'm wodering if this is somehow possible or if there is a workaround or something else for this. I have a normal SELECT statement like this which is used on a DataTable:

```
"Date = 'someValue'";
```

Since I want to first construct the string statements because I later concatenate them dynamically with OR and AND to construct a bigger statement I would need to realize this in a string. What I would need to have is something like:

```
"DateTime.Today > Date + DateTime.Today.AddDays(PayDay)"
```

where PayDay and Date are columns in my DataTable. Is this possible somehow?
This is a search, so I get a new Table with all rows that match this case.

The last statement which executes the string is:

```
 myDt.DefaultView.RowFilter = concatenatedString;
```

Comment: I don't think `RowFilter` support this kind of syntax. How about use this condition in `WHERE` part of your query that fills this DataTable?

Comment: That's the point. Since I create the statement dynamically like mentioned above I get this at the end: myDt.DefaultView.RowFilter = concatenatedString;

Comment: Read the documentation for the `DATEADD` SQL function and you'll be able to adapt your statement accordingly.